# Почему Url::to возвращает значение массива rules, а не ключ?

Tags: yii2

```
 'rules' => [
      'wow/<id:\d+>' => 'site/view',
],
```

в классе actionView:

```
 var_dump(Url::to(['site/view']));
```

В итоге возвращает site/view;
Как получить ключ массива, а не значение?

Comment: А зачем вам ключ?

Comment: @СергейМишин, а значение зачем, если поиск и так делается по значению?

Comment: @Qwertiy а я что-то писал про значение? Нет. Сам вопрос странный, потому что это нигде не должно использоваться, кроме как в настройках конфигурации. И получение ключа означает, что это будет что-то перетираться. Зачем? короч бред

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос, конечно странный, но если надо получить ключ массива по значению, то сделать это можно так.

```
$rules = [
  'wow/<id:\d+>' => 'site/view',
];
$key = array_search('site/view', $rules);

echo $key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что вы хотите сгенерировать адрес страницы и получить что-то вроде `/wow/1`. Если так, то вы забываете добавить параметр с идентификатором.

```
Url::to(['site/view', 'id' => 1])
```

Такой вызов даст в результате строку `/wow/1` или `/index.php?r=site/view&id=1`, если у вас отключены ЧТУ.